# Excel macro to format cells based on value and group with blank rows below

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I'm trying to create an excel macro to format some data that is exported from another program. Here is an example of the data layout:

```
ID        Code      SubCodes
1         A1        1
1                   30
1         B2        23
1                   35
2         A1        1
2                   30
2         A1        6
2                   10
2                   12
2         C3        2
2         C3        4
```

I want to create major "groups" and minor "groups" using formatting. I don't necessarily want to use Excel's grouping feature. I'd like to first group by ID, which is easy enough, and add a large bolded border line after each ID.
The part I'm having trouble with is the minor groups, as the subcodes don't have the parent code on it's line if there is more than 1, and there can be multiple codes with different subcodes that are different. The minor groups would then have a fainter border line after each.

Here is an example of the desired formatting:

```
ID        Code      SubCodes
============================
1         A1        1
1                   30
----------------------------
1         B2        23
1                   35
============================
2         A1        1
2                   30
----------------------------
2         A1        6
2                   10
2                   12
----------------------------
2         C3        2
----------------------------
2         C3        4
============================
```

So how can I get these minor groups to include the rows with blank codes below them?
This would preferably be in a macro as the file is exported from the program, and then will need to be formatted. However if there is a better way, I'm definitely open to that. The end goal is to make the data easily readable.

Here is the code I have now to create the formatting for the major grouping.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim StartRow As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cValue As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    StartRow = "1"
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set Rng = Range("A" & StartRow, "A" & LastRow)

    Cells.ClearOutline

    cValue = Range("A" & StartRow).Value
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell.Value <> cValue Then
            With Cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
        Else
            cValue = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code have you written? What does it do or not do vs what it's supposed to?

Comment: @DavidPostill Apologies, I don't mean to ask someone to write the code for me. I've edited in my code so far. Perhaps I should have been clearer in that I just don't know how to select the rows for the minor groups. (Code and all blank rows to follow)

Comment: @Raystafarian I have updated the OP with my code for the major grouping. Please see my other comment for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (change to your preference) -

```
Sub Macro1()

     Dim LastRow As Integer
     LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     ActiveSheet.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        If c <> c.Offset(1) Then
            With Range(c, c.Offset(, 2)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With

        End If
    Next

    For Each c In Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
        If c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone And c.Offset(1) <> "" Then
            With Range(c.Offset(, -1), c.Offset(, 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDashDot
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The first set of grouping works great. However, there are a few issues with the second. It appears to only format cells that are blank, so it would incorrectly format the `2                   10` row in my example and also not format the `2         C3        2` row which it should

Comment: I guess I don't understand your grouping. I fixed the double blanks, but I don't get the C3 condition.

Comment: In my example, the first grouping is done by the ID (All "1"s in a group, All "2"s in another, etc) However, with the second grouping, codes are grouped with their subcodes, not with similar codes. So in the example the group with ID 2 would have 4 subgroups. The first subgroup would be line `2 A1 1` and line `2 30`. So the code A1 is grouped with it's two subcodes, 1 and 30. The second subgroup would be line `2         A1        6`, line `2 10`, and line `2 12` So the second A1 code would be grouped with it's three subcodes, 6, 10, and 12. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Ok the C3 condition is that the C3 code is on there twice, with two different subcodes that are not grouped into the same code. So it's important to know that there are two C3 codes with separate subcodes, rather than just knowing there was one C3 code with two subcodes.

Comment: I was able to get it by simply removing `c = "" And` This allowed the codes with only one subcode to be formatted. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry as I was away from the computer I figured I should have done top borders instead of bottom